# Bootstrap modal not closing when close is clicked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a grid of books with a layout similar to the Instagram page. Each cell in this grid links to a modal which opens up with information from the server. The modal opens as expected, however, does not close as intended.

That is, the modal closes only when the user clicks within the modal, however, the modal DOESN'T close when the user clicks on the button inside (i.e. '.close').

When I change `link_to` to a button it does open and close correctly. Any suggestions on how to properly fix this while still using the `link_to` rails method?

```
  <ul id="book-list">    
      <% @books.each do |book| %>
        <%= link_to "#book-modal-#{book.id}" , data: { toggle: "modal" }  do %>
          <li id="book">
            <%= image_tag book.image_url, id: "book-image" %>

            <div id="book-modal-<%= book.id%>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><%= book.title %></h4>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><%= book.id%></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Preview -->
            <div id="book-preview">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12-sm text-center" id="book-preview-detail">
                  <h3><%= book.title %></h3>
                  <h4><%= book.price %></h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Comment: How do your rendered HTML look like ?

Comment: See screenshot here: http://imgur.com/HrsYyX0

Comment: We need to see the underlying the HTML and not the page itself.

Comment: See link to gist: https://gist.github.com/byteacademyinstructors/1eabe54e136043460f15

Comment: I figured it out! The link_to is linking to the modal itself and is thus why the element would open again when clicking on the close buttons. ahhh recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your coffee script to 1.8, i had this problem before concerning link_to and button_to

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '~> 1.8.0'
and `run bundle install or update`
```